# Effect of source/input impedance on LDO regulator stability

Tags: voltage-regulator, ldo, stability

The [datasheet](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/aemDocuments/documents/APID/ProductDocuments/DataSheets/MCP1700-Data-Sheet-20001826F.pdf) for the MCP1700 family of LDO voltage regulators, in section 5.1 (p.13) states:

> ...As with all LDO circuits, a relatively low source impedance (10\$\Omega\$) is needed to prevent the input impedance from causing the LDO to become unstable.

It then continues,

> The size and type of the required capacitor...

I might be tempted to think the reference to source impedance was referring to the capacitative reactance of the input side capacitor, but as that is frequency dependent, and the comment about source impedance mentions a specific value in ohms, I am inclined to believe the datasheet is referring to *resistive* impedance. (Of course I could be wrong in that interpretation.)

My question concerns the mechanism, or feedback route, by which the LDO becomes unstable when the source impedance is insufficiently small.

For reference, here is a functional block diagram of MCP1700 devices.

[image]

A Texas Instruments [paper](https://www.ti.com/lit/an/slyt194/slyt194.pdf?ts=1677351286724) entitled "Stability analysis of low-dropout linear regulators with a PMOS pass element" appears to me to make no mention of LDO instability caused by insufficiently small source impedance.

In addition to learning the mechanism or feedback path by which an insufficiently low input impedance may lead to instability, I would also be interesting in learning whether there are any techniques that might be used to mitigate such an instability problem. For example might increasing the value of the input side capacitor allow for a source impedance greater than 10\$\Omega\$? Would inductive reactance in the source make the problem worse? (my guess -- yes).

Comment: The source impedance refers to the combination of resistance, inductance and capacitance on the input line. They're saying that you should design for less than 10 ohms up to whatever frequency the LDO operates at, hence pick a big enough capacitance.

Comment: @user1850479 apart from unwanted oscillations, the LDO operates at DC! So what frequency should be chosen?

Comment: The LDO has a loop bandwidth that extends far above DC (else it would be a resistor). You can get an idea from the ripple rejection ratio, but with reasonable layout the source capacitance means you should be low impedance at high frequencies regardless.

Comment: @user1850479 Sometimes reasonable layout is not an option. What if I want to regulate a voltage at the end of a 600 m cable? So, I want to understand the mechanism behind the instability.

Comment: In practice you should have bulk capacitance at the end of a cable that long regardless, so you would almost certainly hit your target impedance at all relevant frequencies just from best practices and the recommended ceramic capacitor.  As for how you would calculate the minimum values more precisely from the limited datasheet information, I'm not sure. There also doesn't seem to be a spice model.

Comment: @user1850479 So, if the wire has a resistance greater than the 10\$\Omega\$ specified in the datasheet, but the regulator's input capacitance is increased appropriately, everything would be OK? That's what I guess, but since I don't understand _how_ the source resistance affects stability, I am uneasy. You are offering solutions, which are appreciated, but I am looking for a deeper understanding.

Comment: With 10 ohms DC resistance on the input, and 100 mA current, there will be a 1 volt drop from the supply. An LDO is generally used where the input voltage is already limited and voltage drop in the regulator needs to be no more than 1-2 volts or so. Thus I would think a source resistance greater than 10 ohms would be unusual, although I doubt it would cause instability except as obviously would occur under higher currents.

Comment: Impedance is a complex value, so can be plotted on a 2-dimensional plane. Consider the region around 0 ohms, bounded in a circle of radius 10 ohms -- or maybe a rectangle or some other shape. It might also be positive-real only. If the reactance and resistance fall within this region, it's probably fine.

Comment: @TimWilliams. Yes, impedance can be complex valued. However, the reactive component is generally frequency dependent. If the source impedance needs to be less than 10 ohms at _all_ frequencies, then we arrive once again to the conclusion that the resistive component must be less than 10 ohms.  The modulus 
 of Zr || Zc will be less than the modulus of Zr for all frequencies above DC. (Zc being the impedance of the input capacitor).

Comment: Exactly. Now, inductance can increase impedance beyond that circle, but we also don't need *all* frequencies, just all within the control bandwidth of the regulator -- some MHz perhaps. Which is perfectly feasible of course. So that sets the amount of stray inductance or trace length between capacitor and regulator.

Answer (score 4):

When \$V_{IN}\$ decreases due to a load current change, in the absence of control, \$V_{OUT}\$ will decrease. In order to maintain a constant \$V_{OUT}\$, a control loop allows more current to pass from the input.

If the input has a high impedance, then the increased current demand further reduces \$V_{IN}\$, in turn requiring more current. This is a positive feedback situation.

A capacitor across the input will provide the transient current to respond to step changes in load current. So a low ESR,ESL is required to compensate.

---

> the comment about source impedance mentions a specific value in ohms, I am inclined to believe the datasheet is referring to resistive impedance.

This comment refers to a magnitude regardless of phase as in \$10\angle \theta \Omega \$.

Answer (score 1):

While I haven't delved much into this, I feel that the problem LDO regulators have with stability is related to the gain of the pass element being highly variable in a common source setup (below right, LDO), in contrast to the always-unity-gain source-follower arrangement (left, non-LDO):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f6Dtsi.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The LDO pass stage will have gain close to \$\frac{R_4}{R_3}\$ at DC and low frequencies, where R3 is source impedance and R4 is the load. If R3 is significant, load capacitance will cause gain to fall quickly with frequency, along with the associated phase shift.

With R3 unknown to the IC designer, a value upon which gain in particular is so highly dependent, I imagine it is much harder to implement built-in frequency compensation to keep this common-source system stable.

Answer (score 0):

In all LDO specifications there are tables that include line regulation, and load regulation. The first is a transfer function from input to output in attenuation of line input modulation. While load regulation is the ratio of the source, impedance of the output to the output load. These are typically in the +/-1% range. LDO’s will have an output, resistance and feedback gain >50 dB to achieve the load reg. tolerance.

For the load Reg., this is a simple resistive positive 1% typ. transfer function. Adding a load current causes a negative output error removing a load current causes a positive output error. By the way, the ESR on the output caps must be within a certain range to achieve this, as too small on output C ESR can reduce the feedback gain and cause more ringing. That is normal, but next, I’ll explain how it can be unstable for line regulation Cap ESR.

If you look at the plots for line regulation, output = vertical and input = horizontal, you’ll see that the slope is negative. This may be counterintuitive, but means that if you have resistance outside the source input, causing the line to change and you have negative feedback to correct for the 1% output changes if the input has more than 1%, then it can become positive feedback.

Normally, you would think the transfer function for line regulation would be a positive attenuation, but **in this P type MOSFET configuration it has a negative Line Reg. Transfer Function and if ESR on input cap is >10 ohms, such as a 10 uF e-cap then the load noise loop gain is positive >1**.

This would never happen in BJT type LDO’s as the Line Reg. is a positive slope (if you tested it as plots may not be given).

Proof is not given at this time.